# star pyramid print each second

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have a simple pyramid print for loop. I works fine but I wanted to add a little twist to the loop. I want to print each star per second. So I added a setinterval. When I added the interval it breaks the pyramid and  it does not show per second.

```js
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  var totalNumberofRows = this.value;
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalNumberofRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            setInterval(function(){ 
            
            document.write("*");
            
            }, i * 1000);
            
        }
        document.write("<br>");
        
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class='target'>
```

Comment: You're declaring a new interval for every asterisk to be printed.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen i see that is why its in one line i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.write` will clear the existing document if it's loaded - and if the script runs asynchronously, the script *will* be loaded by then. Your interval also never ends at the moment.

I'd `await` a delay right before adding a `*` instead:

```js
const delay = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
// Add a change listener to the .target element
$(".target").change(async function() {
  // Figure out the total number of rows by taking the value from the input field
  var totalNumberofRows = this.value;
  // Iterate from 1 to the totalNumberofRows
  for (let i = 1; i <= totalNumberofRows; i++) {
    // Create a row, append it to the body
    const row = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      // Add a character to the row
      row.textContent += '*';
      // Wait until 1000ms has passed before continuing
      await delay();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class='target'>
```

Comment: this is what I am trying to do. Actually I dont know what delay and await does does i look into thanks for the ideas. If its not that demanding can you add a little comment on each line?

Answer (score 0):

That's a tough one.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= totalNumberofRows; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= i;) {
            printSlow(j, function(){
              j++
            })

    }

function printSlow(qty) {
  let counter = qty
  let printer = setInterval(function() {
    if (counter > 0) {
      document.print('*')
      counter --
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(printer)
      document.print('<br />')
      callback()
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

setInterval is async, so you have to account for that. You also need to clear the interval once you get what you need from it.
The original loop will probably need some tweaks.